# Cannot publish data to Xively

Tags: python, xively

I'm trying to upload some temp data to a feed in `Xively` but for the life of me I just cannot get it to work! The data is being read and printed by the RPi however no data is being pushed to `Xively`. I've used the tutorial code and was able to have that push data but I can't seem to replicate that with my own code. I get no errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import xively
import subprocess
import time
import datetime
import requests
import glob

# extract feed_id and api_key from environment variables
FEED_ID = 1374874100
API_KEY = 'ONdefUJlt3d5cifAvTYocqvOPm824F3P1QnT99OtdKQpL7ZD'
DEBUG = 'TRUE'


# initialize api client
api = xively.XivelyAPIClient(API_KEY)

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# My temp probe details
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device1_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-00000503b862')[0]
device1_file = device1_folder + '/w1_slave'

# Function to read temp sensor
def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device1_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
        lines = read_temp_raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
                time.sleep(0.2)
                lines = read_temp_raw()
        equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos != -1:
                temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
                temp_c = float(temp_string) /1000
                return temp_c

while True:
        print("Temp is currently...", read_temp())
        time.sleep(5)


# function to return a datastream object. This either creates a new datastream,
# or returns an existing one
def get_datastream(feed):
  try:
    datastream = feed.datastreams.get("FermTemp")
    if DEBUG:
      print "Found existing datastream"
    return datastream
  except:
    if DEBUG:
      print "Creating new datastream"
    datastream = feed.datastreams.create("FermTemp", tags="temp_01")
    return datastream


# main program entry point - runs continuously updating our datastream with the
# current temps
def run():
  print "Getting Fermentation Temps"

  feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)

  datastream = get_datastream(feed)
  datastream.max_value = None
  datastream.min_value = None

  while True:
    FermentationTemp = read_temp()
    datastream.current_value = FermentationTemp
    datastream.at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    try:
      datastream.update()
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
      print "HTTPError({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)

    time.sleep(10)

run()
```

It seems as though as soon as I take out the bit that defines the temp data, it's happy to then connect to the relevant `Xively` channel.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the return type of 'FermentationTemp' variable. Typecast 'FermentationTemp' into string and try .